# Build kurento-media-server error

Tags: kurento

I want to build kurento-media-server from source code : https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server

At last i get this error message:

```
ubuntu@VM-117-216-ubuntu:~/kurento-media-server$ make kurento-media-server
[ 26%] Built target websocketTransport
[ 33%] Built target transport
Linking CXX executable kurento-media-server
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/kurento-media-server.dir/loadConfig.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path3endEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [server/kurento-media-server] Error 1
make[2]: *** [server/CMakeFiles/kurento-media-server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [server/CMakeFiles/kurento-media-server.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [kurento-media-server] Error 2
```

It tells that i should add -lboost_system, I assume it should be added after gcc or g++, but Makefiles which generated by cmake are complicated and I can't find where to add it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the build to work you should follow these steps:

a) **Clone** the project: `git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server.git`

b) Go to `kurento-media-server/debian/control` and check the `Build-Depends`.

c) Most important dependencies you need are:

```
 1. sudo apt-get install cmake
 2. sudo apt-get install debhelper
 3. sudo apt-get install binutils
 4. sudo apt-get install kms-core-6.0-dev
 5. sudo apt-get install kms-elements-6.0-dev
 6. sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
 7. sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
 8. sudo apt-get install pkg-config
 9. sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

d) Finally build:

```
  1. cmake .
  2. make -j4
  3. sudo make install
```

Should work just fine :)